# Why should 'no terminal should control the process' option be set in serial port?

Tags: c, linux, terminal, serial-port

```
fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0",O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);    
                               /* O_NOCTTY - No terminal will control the process   */
```

Why should we specify or not specify this option? What does it do and doesn't do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's answered in the documentation for [GNU C library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Open_002dtime-Flags.html#index-O_005fNOCTTY):

> If the named file is a terminal device, don’t make it the controlling terminal for the process. See [Job Control](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html#Job-Control), for information about what it means to be the controlling terminal.
>
> On GNU/Hurd systems and 4.4 BSD, opening a file never makes it the controlling terminal and **`O_NOCTTY`** is zero. However, GNU/Linux systems and some other systems use a nonzero value for **`O_NOCTTY`** and set the controlling terminal when you open a file that is a terminal device; so to be portable, use **`O_NOCTTY`** when it is important to avoid this.

That is, since the USB serial device is treated like a terminal, use the flag is you don't intend for it to be ***like*** a terminal and allow the device to start/stop jobs (e.g., processes) which happen to be connected to it with a given user.

Further reading:

- [What is the purpose of the controlling terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404555/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-controlling-terminal)